# ksoap2 sending an abstract class with attribute type

Tags: java, blackberry, ksoap2

I'm having a problem creating a request from Ksoap2 on BlackBerry, I have to create the following XML:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:pol="http://osde.com.ar/services/binaria/personas/poliza" xmlns:bin="http://binaria.entities.osde.com.ar" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <pol:getPoliza>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <pol:polizaVinculada i:type="bin:PolizaVinculadaVIT">
            <bin:idPoliza>49116</bin:idPoliza>
            <bin:idSolicitud>30261352</bin:idSolicitud>
         </pol:polizaVinculada>
      </pol:getPoliza>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

With the `i:type="bin:PolizaVinculadaVIT"`, being `polizaVinculada` an abstract class and `PolizaVinculadaVIT` a subclass of `PolizaVinculada`

Does anybody know how to do this ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is about sending complex objects.

You can find more info about it on the following site:
http://seesharpgears.blogspot.com/2010/10/ksoap-android-web-service-tutorial-with.html

In summary your PolizaVinculada must implement the KvmSerializable interface and then add the mapping to the Soap envelope.

Saludos.